# pipe and thread safety

Tags: linux, network-programming, thread-safety, pipe

I create a pipe and a thread in my linux C program. So there are 2 threads: main thread and the second thread.

The second thread writes bytes into the pipe.

In the main thread, I register an `EV_READ` event(libevent, it is similar to `read` event in epoll/poll) for the pipe. When there are bytes available in the pipe, the event is triggered.

are there any thread safety problem in this pipe usage?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  You have one writer and one reader so there is no conflict.  The pipe reads and writes are guaranteed to be atomic up to `PIPE_BUF` size so even you had multiple readers and writers as long as each read/write is below PIPE_BUF size you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: what you mean is: 1 if there is only 1 writer and 1 reader, it doesn't matther how much each write is.  2 if there are multiple readers and writers,as long as each call of read/write is below PIPE_BUF, it is thread safe. Am I right? thanks

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.